# Interface type method parameter implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to do like this:

```
interface IDBBase {
     DataTable getDataTableSql(DataTable curTable,IDbCommand cmd);
     ...
}

class DBBase : IDBBase {
     public DataTable getDataTableSql(DataTable curTable, SqlCommand cmd) {
         ...
     }
}
```

I want to use the interface to implement to d/t providers (MS-SQL,Oracle...); in it there are some signatures to be implemented in the corresponding classes that implement it. I also tried like this:

```
genClass<typeOj>
{
    typeOj instOj;

    public  genClass(typeOj o)
    {      instOj=o;    }


    public typeOj getType()
    {        return instOj;    }
```

...

```
interface IDBBase 
{
    DataTable getDataTableSql(DataTable curTable,genClass<idcommand> cmd);
    ...
}

class DBBase : IDBBase 
{
    public DataTable getDataTableSql(DataTable curTable, genClass<SqlCommand> cmd)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible. Method should have same signature that one declared in the interface.

However you can use type parameter constraints:

```
interface IDBClass<T> where T:IDbCommand
{
    void Test(T cmd);
}

class DBClass:IDBClass<SqlCommand>
{
    public void Test(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) are not widely supported as of C# 3.0, except for assigning method groups to delegates. You can emulate it a bit by using private interface implementation and call public method with more specific parameters:

```
class DBBase : IDBBase {

    DataTable IDBBase.getDataTableSql(DataTable curTable, IDbCommand cmd) {
         return getDataTableSql(curTable, (SqlCommand)cmd); // of course you should do some type checks
     }

     public DataTable getDataTableSql(DataTable curTable, SqlCommand cmd) {
         ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling it.  The compiler will report an error if `DBBase` doesn't implement `IDBBase`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. I tried compiling this:

```
interface Interface1 { }
class Class1 : Interface1 {}

interface Interface2 { void Foo(Interface1 i1);}
class Class2 : Interface2 {void Foo(Class1 c1) {}}
```

And I got this error:

> *'Class2' does not implement interface member 'Interface2.Foo(Interface1)'*